# Angular 7 mat-table each row reusable component

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

How can each row in mat-table be reusable component ?

In regular html table i use this approach

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left width-50" ></th>
            <th class="text-left width-85">Id</th>
            <th class="text-left">Price</th>
            <th class="text-left width-160">City</th>
            <th class="text-left width-160">State</th>
            <th class="text-left width-160">Qty</th>
            <th class="text-left width-160">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
      <tr pdp-adjustment-list-item *ngFor="let currentItem of pagedResponse?.content"  
         (idCheckedOutput)="addItemIdToCheckedArray($event)"
         [item]="currentItem" >
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

pdp-adjustment-list-item is selector of AdjustmentListItemComponent.
This is convenient because each row is one same instance of AdjustmentListItemComponent with reactive form and one @Input() item i pass object in in a loop.

This is clean and intuitive.

Now, in Angular7 material table examples i could find everything is placed in one uber component.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

If this is true, and you actually must keep everything in one uber component, this will not only be poor design choice when we talk about reusability, but also having to keep everything in one component creates huge mess of spaghetti code.

So way around this would be to dynamically create one reactive form for each row in uber component, and then utilize form array, but what is the point? Actually i did that and decided to delete it because code would be totally unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like pdp-adjustment-list-item  is something like

```
<td *ngFor="let ....
```

but is exactly the same here, you define the columns and the rows are generated dynamically based on the "datasource".

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

you even can make the columns definitions been generated dynamically

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                        {{ element[column] }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

[Inspect this example from the material docs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgjemqkyqog?file=app%2Ftable-http-example.ts)

[Example of material with reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-table)

Comment: How would i achieve "one reactive form per one row" using this approach? How would this help me when i need each row to carry certain logic?  I have no problem what so ever simply displaying data.

Comment: `rows: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ 'streams': this.rows,
    });`

rows will be populated when you get your datasource, you will create one formGoup per row and you can access them by index. 

`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" [formGroupName]="index">`

Comment: [Example with reactive forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-table)

Comment: this is actually really good. Much simpler than what i originally wrote. thnks